# Need 12-h time formatting in Excel

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

Consider an Excel sheet with one column of bad data. We have a table that can be used to correct the data. My code runs it by writing a new sheet containing the old sheet plus adding new columns of correct data for them to compare.

This date is fine and works but it makes the date/time into a format with 24-h time.

How can this be changed to use the preferred format?

```
newSheet.Cells[i + 2, 3] = drugorder.DATE;
newSheet.Cells[i + 2, 3].NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy h:mm";
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apparently, the `h` specifier in an Excel date format will only use 12-hour time if you include an `AM/PM` specifier in the number format as well.

The seemingly logical `.NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy h:mm"` produces:

```
2/13/1922 5:19
5/17/1927 21:13
```

While `.NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy h:mm AM/PM"` produces the intended:

```
2/13/1922 5:19 AM
5/17/1927 9:13 PM
```